# Datatype to Store Longitude/Latitude in Mysql

Tags: mysql, floating-point, geospatial, sqldatatypes

```
'43.005895','-71.013202'
```

Trying to use:

```
INSERT INTO table(fanDetLocZip, fanDetLocCity, fanDetLocState, fanDetLocLat, fanDetLocLong, fanDetLocTZ, fanDetLocDST)  
VALUES(00210, 'Portsmouth', 'NH', '43.005895', '-71.013202', -5, 1);
```

I'm currently using the datatype `SPATIAL`, `GEOMETRY`.

Its giving me errors like:

Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field

All the values have 2 digits, and 6 decimal places after decimal. How do I store this in mysql?

Error I get when I use:
`INSERT INTO Table(fanDetLocZip, fanDetLocCity, fanDetLocState, fanDetLocLatLong, fanDetLocTZ, fanDetLocDST)

VALUES(00210, 'Portsmouth', 'NH', point(43.005895,-71.013202), -5,1)`

Error Image:[image: img5]

Comment: Can you add the table's definition (`CREATE` statement)? Which column is of type `GEOMETRY` ?

Comment: That's two columns. Do you have a column of type GEOMETRY or POINT ?

Comment: YES, Those two are type GEOMETRY

Comment: *Please* post the create or describe table? It doesn't make sense to give advice without it.

Comment: @user975947: The names you have chosen (`Lat` and `Long`) indicate you haven't understood how Geometry fields work. You have both a Latitude and a Longitude stored inside one field.

Comment: Please see error I'm encountering above.

Comment: Should that value that's inputted look like that?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use `POINT()` to store into a column of type `GEOMETRY` or `POINT`:

```
POINT(43.005895, -71.013202)
```

If the Geometry column is named `geom`, you can use this:

```
INSERT INTO table
    ( ..., geom, ...) 
  VALUES
    ( ..., POINT(43.005895, -71.013202), ...)
```

---

If you want to show data stored, you can use the [`X()` and `Y()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/geometry-property-functions.html#point-property-functions) functions:

```
SELECT X(geom) AS x, Y(geom) AS y
FROM table
```

Comment: This is helpful, I am guessing I just didnt add point() . Never have used geometry values before. Thanks ypercube!

Comment: When I use: INSERT INTO Table(fanDetLocZip, fanDetLocCity,fanDetLocState,fanDetLocLatLong,fanDetLocTZ,fanDetLocDST) VALUES(00210,'Portsmouth','NH',point(43.005895,-71.013202),-5,1)   it inputs the value weird. See screenshot above.

Comment: Weird, well, that atleast works. Maybe its a browser bug or something. Thanks YPerCube!

Comment: Shouldn't be the POINT be POINT(43.005895 -71.013202) as described here?
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gis-wkt-format.html

Answer (score 2):

Why dont you use instead a Float type for your lat/long?

```
Float (10,6)
```

Comment: float is not good to store lattitude and longtitude. Double is the best datatype to store lattitude/longtitude. [Read Complete Discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20657172/float-and-double-datatype-is-good-to-store-lattitude-and-longtitude)