# data type of longitude and latitude to store in mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm designing a table in mysql that will store a list of users and a Google Maps co-ordinate (longitude & latitude).

Will I need two fields, or can it be done with 1?

I don't know what I use?
what I use float or decimal or GEOMETRY or there is new data type?
 what are the pros and cons of the best data type to choose it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the ideal data type to use when storing latitude / longitudes in a MySQL database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159255/what-is-the-ideal-data-type-to-use-when-storing-latitude-longitudes-in-a-mysql)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [spatial extensions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/spatial-extensions.html) in mysql 
the datatype is [POINT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/gis-class-point.html)

It will be faster in search , and many features for geographic operation.

Comment: this is the best solution for this data type
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560147/datatype-to-store-longitude-latitude-in-mysql

Answer (score 3):

A proper way, and fast, is described on this blog:

http://www.rooftopsolutions.nl/blog/229

```
CREATE TABLE geo (
  longitude DOUBLE,
  latitude DOUBLE,
  idxlong SMALLINT,
  idxlat SMALLINT,
  INDEX (idxlong,idxlat);
);
```

Part 2 contains a benchmark: http://www.rooftopsolutions.nl/blog/230

```
method  small   medium  large
plain select        1.73s
index on latitude       0.72s
using point field       9.52s
using point field + spatial index   0.00s   0.73s   18.82s
using morton number     0.78s
index on morton 0.00s   0.65s   3.23s
```

Also a part 3 with in practice: http://www.rooftopsolutions.nl/blog/231

Comment: note that it is quite easy to convert long,lat columns to a 'spatially enabled' column, using:

--Add a spatially

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

- a pair of `DECIMAL(11, 8)` (3 digits before and 8 digits after decimal)
- a pair of `FLOAT`

Note that a decimal column can store an exact value, where as a float column stores an approximation of the value. For example `1.999999` will be stored as `1.999999` in the decimal column but as `2.0` in the float column.