# float and double datatype is good to store latitude and longitude?

Tags: java, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, precision, type-conversion

I am storing latitude and longitude at the server side (JAVA Platform).

To store those values, I am using float and double datatype at the server side. I came to know that float and double are not a recommended primitive datatypes (which is not recommended to use currencies in professional way), because float and double having **rounding precision problem**.

In my case, I am just comparing the stored coordinates (latitude and longitude) at the server side.

**Question 1:**

Comparing the coordinates with the datatypes (float or double) will make any problem in future?

**Question 2:**

Using big decimal is good? or Going with float or double is safer?

Comment: 6 decimal places (which is max precision of a float)  is enough. See http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/8674

Comment: @JarrodRoberson This question is about Java, the other question is about MySQL. How can this question be a duplicate then?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's not a matter of safety, its just a matter of precision.
I wouldn't consider floats, but doubles are what i think are ideal here.
You just need to see what's the most precision you can get out of a double and see if it fits a regular longitude/latitude value. I think it's more then enough.

Else BigDecimal is just a simple backdoor to your problem, use it if you want more precision

Comment: For curious, Wanted to know How much precision the double can handle. As per my observation, It can handle 14 digits of precision (to my case). So I think It is good for me. If double can handle more than 20 digits, double would be the ideal for my app. Your suggestion please .

Comment: depending on the java you are using, the double primitive datatype is 64 bits long with of course 1 digit for the sine, etc..
You can find the information on the precision here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.3

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable guidance.

Answer (score 34):

You should start with [the accuracy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_degrees) you desire. Once you have determined that, you can choose a data type that is suitable.

If you decide that an accuracy of 5 decimal places (1.1132 m) is enough, you can easily go with `float`. The more accurate your calculation needs to be, the more you should lean towards using `double` and eventually `BigDecimal`.

When comparing floating point numbers, you should incorporate the necessary precision as well.

Comment: +1 for this answer. Check this link to have an idea of the precision you need http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3AWikiProject_Geographical_coordinates#Precision

Comment: 1 degree of latitude or longitude is about 111km. Also: `double l = -179.123456789; System.out.println((float)f);` prints: `-179.15346`, then you can estimate an accuracy around 1m only if you code it with 'float' (4 bytes)

Comment: Usually I do not expect (civil) GPS in a smartphone to be more precise than 1m so for most cases float should be fine.

Answer (score 4):

you will not have to do any rounding on your longitude or latitude values, so use whichever one you want. Double is more precise, so let that be the most important factor in your decision.

How much precision do your long/lat values need?

For pinpoint accuracy on a map, you might want to look at big decimal, but for vague values, float is good enough.

Comment: It might need 20 digit. But Not sure. As per my observation this is the case. And of course I am not doing any rounding operations. I am simply checking the following condition   if((swLat <= lattitude) && (swLng <= longtitude) && (neLat >= lattitude) && (neLng >= longtitude)) ... If i have implemented with double, the condition is working fine. But fear to use it, Because I need accuracy. Using Double is a ideal option for my case ?