# PHP Data Type For MySQL POINT Field

Tags: php, mysql, geospatial, spatial, sqldatatypes

I created a MySQL table where a field is of type `POINT` and is used to store lat, lon coordinates (ex: 36.6294654 -93.1725982).

I got an error, with a form submission, and I'm assuming it is due to a mismatched data type.

```
SQLSTATE[22003]: Numeric value out of range: 1416 Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field
```

My understanding is that `POINT` should have the example's format (I also tried lat, lon).  The problem, I think, is that the space converts the variable into `STRING`.

Am I missing something, here?

Here is my PHP code to connect to the database and insert the record.

```
// use google's geocoding service to transform an address into lat/lon coordinates (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/)
$json = file_get_contents('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' . urlencode($street) . ',+' . urlencode($city) . ',+' . urlencode($state) . ',+' . urlencode($zip) . '&key=YOUR_API_KEY');
$json = json_decode($json, true);
$latlon = $json['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'] . ' ' . $json['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'];
try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=someserver;port=someport;dbname=somedatabase', 'someusername', 'somepassword', array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO Venues (Name, Street, City, State, Zip, Country, TimeZone, LatLon, Phone, Email, Website, Host, Notes) VALUES (:name, :street, :city, :state, :zip, :country, :timezone, :latlon, :phone, :email, :website, :host, :notes)';
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array(":name" => $name, ":street" => $street, ":city" => $city, ":state" => $state, ":zip" => $zip, ":country" => $country, ":timezone" => $timezone, ":latlon" => $latlon, ":phone" => $phone, ":email" => $email, ":website" => $website, ":host" => $host, ":notes" => $notes));
    if ($stmt->rowCount() == 1) {
        echo '<p>"' . $name . '" creation succeeded.</p>';
    } else {
        echo '<p>"' . $name . '" creation failed.</p>';
    }
    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $dbh = null;
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Alternatively, I could just have separate lat and lon fields, but I was wanting to practice with msyql's built-in geometry functionality.

Edit...

Following the advise of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9560215/953702), I surrounded `$latlon` with `POINT()`.  It didn't change the results, though.

Edit 2...

Here is the table structure, just in case something doesn't look correct.

```
VenueKey    int(11)
Name        varchar(255)
Street      varchar(255)
City        varchar(255)
State       varchar(2)
Zip         varchar(10)
Country     varchar(2)
TimeZone    varchar(20)
LatLon      point
Phone       varchar(20)
Email       varchar(255)
Website     varchar(255)
Host        varchar(255)
Notes       text
```

Comment: is it because you're missing a comma between lat and lon?

Comment: @Ronnie I tried `POINT(lat, lon)`, `POINT(lat lon)`, and `POINT(lat,lon)`.  They all resulted in the error.

Comment: maybe give this answer a shot: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17893691/how-to-insert-point-data-into-mysql-using-pdo-bindparam sounds like you need to be using `PointFromText`

Comment: @Ronnie That link had the answer (same as Prisoner's answer), but it wasn't clearly defined that `PointFromText()` HAD to be in the query.  I assumed that its inclusion in the variable was the same thing.  It wasn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should fix your issue:

```
$latlng = 'POINT(' . $json['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat']. " " . $json['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng']. ')';
```

and then wrap your `:latlon` with `PointFromText`:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO Venues (Name, Street, City, State, Zip, Country, TimeZone, LatLon, Phone, Email, Website, Host, Notes) VALUES (:name, :street, :city, :state, :zip, :country, :timezone, PointFromText(:latlon), :phone, :email, :website, :host, :notes)';
```

Comment: That worked!!!  What, exactly, is the difference between putting `PointFromText()` in the variable versus the query?

Comment: Did you try it with PointFromText() in the var? I don't see why it wouldn't work. On a side note, Prisoner looks like that guy from vsauce on youtube

Comment: @Ronnie Yes, I did try `PointFromText()` in the variable.  The link that you gave, above, referenced that `parameterizing queries is not (simple) string replacement`.  It's possible that it being in the query is interpreted, differently, by MySQL.